# Draw points all over my form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want to draw 1px points allover my form

example:

```
1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite 
1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite 
1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite 1pxBlack 1pxwhite
```

Comment: Anything that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setPixel`

example:

```
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
    For y = 0 To Me.Height - 1
        For x = 0 To Me.Width - 1
            If x Mod 2 = 0 And y Mod 2 = 0 Then
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black)
            Else
                bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Me.BackgroundImage = bmp
```